# Update query, nested iif SET and joined tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to make an Update Query with inner join and have the SET reflect the current month number.

Need help with syntax on updating a joined table that has columns for months, need to update the months that are Month(DATE()) +1,+2 only. Trying to use the below nested IIF as "IIF(Month(Date()) ="1",( SET table.c = table2.c2......) complete code below.

Syntax error is the result

Sample data
[to update sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7TCD.png)
[linked excel with values to use for updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e3je.png)

```
Update dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test

INNER JOIN MasterSalesForecastUpdate

ON (dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.SubTo=MasterSalesForecastUpdate.Item) AND( dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.Planner=MasterSalesForecastUpdate.Planner)

IIF(Month(Date()) ="1",( SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:1] = [MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYJan],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:2] = [MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYFan],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:3] = [MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYMar])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="2",( SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:2]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYFeb],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:3]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYMar],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:4]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYApr])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="3",( SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:3]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYMar],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:4]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYApr],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:5]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYMay])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="4",(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:4]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYApr],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:5]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYMay],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:6]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYJun])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="5",(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:5]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYMay],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:6]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYJun],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:7]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYJul])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="6",(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:6]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYJun],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:7]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYJul],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:8]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYAug])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="7",(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:7]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYJul],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:8]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYAug],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:9]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYSep])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="8",(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:8]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYAug],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:9]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYSep],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:10]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYOct])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="9",(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:9]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYSep],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:10]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYOct],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:11]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYNov])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="10",(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:10]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYOct],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:11]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYNov],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:12]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYDec])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="11",(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:11]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYNov],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:12]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYDec],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY+1:1]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YY+1Jan])

,

IIF(Month(Date())="12"(SET

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY:12]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YYDec],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY+1:1]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YY+1Jan],

dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.[YY+1:02]=[MasterSalesForecastUpdate].[YY+1Feb])



)))))))))));
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result. Columns for months sounds like non-normalized data structure. What happens when you run this? Might be easier to accomplish in VBA.

Comment: added table snips - get a syntax error with the mess of nested iifs.

Comment: Data should be provided as text tables in question, not linked files or images. Or go to a forum where attaching files is encouraged.

Comment: For one thing, Month(Date()) will return a number so don't put criteria in quote marks. `IIF(Month(Date())=1,(`. Also, don't repeat SET within each IIf(), it should be used only once in SQL statement outside IIf(). Is data in SQLServer?

Comment: In Access I would use Choose() instead of IIf for this situation. Often Switch() is preferable to IIf(). SQLServer uses CASE(). But I am not even sure the fields can be conditional. I will have to experiment.

Comment: MS ACCESS is linked to the SQL table dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test and to a Excel file  [MasterSalesForecastUpdate].    The result should update the SQL table to match the Excel tables using the Inner join and the MONTH(DATE()) to only update the corresponding column in the SQL table dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test that contains 24 months of columns for a given SKU/Planner combination. The Excel file only has the planner sku and 3 columns for months that have formulas as the header name. Over all goal is to have a place a planner can paste their sku with forecast and run this update to update SQL.

Comment: sql table has 10K skus and should only be updated to match values to those in the excel file as users paste in new values for the forecasts, hence the inner join on the update

Comment: Do field names actually have YY characters?

Comment: Yes - dbo is YY:1 YY:2 YY:3 YY:4 YY:5 YY:6 YY:7 YY:8.... YY in dbo represents current year and mo number combined. Excel is YYJul YYAug YYSep, The idea is to only ever update the short term forecast with the current month to +2 mo.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot conditionally reference fields. Field must be static in query object then value to update with can be determined in an IIf() for each field. Use VBA to build and execute action SQL statement.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test " & _
     "INNER JOIN MasterSalesForecastUpdate " & _
     "ON (dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.SubTo=MasterSalesForecastUpdate.Item) " & _
          "AND (dbo_MasterSalesForecast_Test.Planner=MasterSalesForecastUpdate.Planner) " & _
     "SET [YY:" & Month(Date()) & "] = [YY" & Format(Date(),"mmm") & "]," & _
         "[YY:" & Month(DateAdd("m",1,Date())) & "] = [YY" & Format(DateAdd("m",1,Date()),"mmm") & "]," & _
         "[YY:" & Month(DateAdd("m",2,Date())) & "] = [YY" & Format(DateAdd("m",2,Date()),"mmm") & "]"
```

Comment: dbo is ODBC linked - what is the syntax for the begining of this code? Need to setup the begining and end to this > a sample I found searching was  `Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim updateQuery As String

updateQuery = "My_Update_Query"

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef
qdf.SQL = updateQuery

qdf.Execute dbFailOnError`

Comment: Did you try the code I provided without anything else? Decide what event to put it in, such as a button click. If it won't run as is then add the db and qdf variable objects setup. The point is, build and execute SQL statement in VBA.

Comment: Code without anything else was runtime error 3016 too few parameters. Expected 3. Novice here so adding the db and qft variables objects are not obvious yet. Will check this out.

Comment: Conflicting info. Your SQL shows YY:01 but data image shows YY:1. Which is correct? Edit your question. Modify suggested code as appropriate.

Comment: No 0's in headers - 10-4 ty

Comment: Ok, revised answer.